# java.lang.AssertionError: Status 404

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Im having 404 error on this test , Im trying to figure out why its giving me this error could someone help me please

this is my controller :

```
 @PostMapping("/infoUtile/add/{idUser}")
    public InformationUtile addOrEditProcedure(@PathVariable(value = "idUser") Long id){
        User user = this.userService.getUser(id);
        InformationUtile info = new InformationUtile();
        info.setUser(user);
        return this.infoUtileService.addOrEditInfoUtile(info);
    }
```

and this is the test that I wrote

```
 @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @MockBean
    InformationUtileService informationUtileService;

    @MockBean
    UserService userService;

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Test
    public void givenInformationsUtiles_whenGetInfoUtiles_thenReturnJsonArray()
            throws Exception {

        InformationUtile informationUtile = new InformationUtile();
        informationUtile.setId(1);
        informationUtile.setContent("oumaima");
        informationUtile.setDescription("test");
        Media medias = new Media();
        medias.setType("image/png");
        medias.setUrl("C:\\files\\actualite\\32769\\adobexd.png");
        List<Media> allMedias = new ArrayList<Media>();
        allMedias.add(medias);
        informationUtile.setMedias(allMedias);
        OngoingStubbing<User> user = Mockito.when(userService.getUser(Mockito.anyLong())).thenReturn(new User());
        Mockito.when(informationUtileService.addOrEditInfoUtile(Mockito.any(InformationUtile.class))).thenReturn(informationUtile);
        mockMvc.perform(post("/infoUtile/add/{id}",informationUtile.getId())
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(mapper.writeValueAsBytes(informationUtile)))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

    }
```

log

[image]

Comment: maybe there's some context-path set someplace?

Comment: no there is no context-path @Jan

Comment: Does the request hit the controller method? Maybe it finds no mapping, therefore returns 404, or maybe it is produced by the controller method itself.

Comment: yes it hits the controller but stopped in the setUser .. I dont know why @MensurQulami

Comment: Could you please provide the log, @Oumaima ?

Comment: I added it @MensurQulami

Comment: You can either debug, or use a `try catch` block to find the problem. You can put the entire method body of the controller into a try catch and log the exception, because definitely there's an exception.

Comment: when I debug the code it redirect me to another method it s weird @MensurQulami

Comment: You are probably doing "step into" instead of "step over". Just try "try catch"

Comment: no Im doing step over , normally when you have two post method in the same controller it normally shouldnt make an ambiguity right ? @MensurQulami

Comment: Depends on their endpoints. The same endpoints with the same "accepts" parameters will cause problems. But as I said, try to catch the exception and see what's going on. MockMvc probably catches and resolves the exception in Exception Handling Controller Advice or something.

Comment: when I used try and catch there is no problem in the MockMvc but when I debug it redirects me to another method in the controller (delete method ) weird @MensurQulami

Comment: You should try an catch the method body of "addOrEditProcedure", something like this: https://hastebin.com/acewiyiziz.cs

Comment: @MensurQulami I did it but the test doesnt execute it

Comment: What is the exception/error?

Comment: it doesnt show nothing because like it doesnt enter the method .. I still dont know why @MensurQulami

Comment: but you said that it reaches "setUser" part.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and in my case the solution was to use full path
from `@RequestMapping` (controller annotation)  + `@PostMapping` (method annotation)

I don't know if this is the case for you. You don't show your controller class. But  if you have something like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class SomeController {

    @PostMapping("/infoUtile/add/{idUser}")
    public InformationUtile addOrEditProcedure(@PathVariable(value = "idUser") Long id) {...}

}
```

then the path in test will be

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/api/v1/infoUtile/add/{idUser}",informationUtile.getId())
```